# java 1.6.0_71 SSL issues

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

I have an application which works fine under java 1.6.0_65 but not under 1.6.0_71. Not sure what changed.
For some other reasons I am not able to upgrade to java 7
I am using unlimited strength jce
any suggestions??

Thanks

S

```
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
No cached client session
Open sessions: 150
ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1395701354 bytes = { 36, 239, 24, 37, 167, 23, 252, 227, 90, 85, 90,     17, 59, 90, 195, 240, 248, 138, 195, 53, 1
```

18, 52, 97, 124, 234, 0, 161, 196 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,    TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECD
SA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SS
L_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_ED
E_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1,  secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, se
ct283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1}
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]

```
TP-Processor2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 115
TP-Processor2, received EOFException: error
TP-Processor2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host  closed connection during handshake
TP-Processor2, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
TP-Processor2, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
TP-Processor2, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
TP-Processor2, called closeSocket()
```

2014-03-25 17:01:30,677 ERROR [CommonUtils:294] Remote host closed connection during handshake
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
        at   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
        at

Comment: What do you call 65 and 71 here? The latest Oracle JDK 1.6 release is u45

Comment: 45 is the last publicly available version of java 6, but if you pay oracle they can provide you later versions

Comment: Well then, why not ask their support?